# SESSION Refresh after form submission

Tags: php, session

I can't understand a thing, for example, after a form is submitted and PHP is refreshed (I clicked the button, and the PHP is fully processed), the page will auto-refreshed?

Comment: share your codes so we can help you better

Comment: You can set your session after form submission. You should set your session at the top of the page. Whenever user fills the form, you can store the form values in the session variable. You can set a flag variable in your form that tracks you have submitted the form.

Comment: @parpar i rewrited the answer

Comment: @Arfan Mahmood wow thanks a lot for the tips!!!It worked, i wanted print the session!!!

Comment: Hopefully, your button in form is <input type="submit">. If you don't want to automatically refresh then change it to <input type="button">.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple, for exmaple if you wont print a session, but you have seted up it on php, you need to put the session print, under the php!